# safari error angular controller not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I have a error where Safari is trowing error that my controllers are not a function

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TranslateController' is not a function, got undefined

My router calling controller here ->

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('welcome.module')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,
      $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('welcome', {
          url: '/welcome',
          views: {
            'header': {
              templateUrl: 'app/welcome/header.html',
              controller: 'TranslateController'
            },
            'sidebar': {},
            'content': {
              templateUrl: 'app/welcome/welcome.html',
              controller: 'WelcomeController'
            },
            'footer': {
              templateUrl: 'app/welcome/footer.html',
              controller: 'WelcomeFooterController'
            }
          }
        })
    }]);
})();
```

My controller ->

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  
  angular
    .module('welcome.module')
    .controller('TranslateController', TranslateCtrl);

  TranslateCtrl.$inject = ['$translate', '$scope'];
  function TranslateCtrl($translate, $scope) {
    'ngInject';
    const self = this;
    $scope.headerFix = true;

    activate();

    function activate() {
      translate();
    }

    function translate() {
      $scope.changeLanguage = function(langKey) {
        $translate.use(langKey);
      };
    }

  }

})();
```

I have definition of the module of course:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('welcome.module', [
            'ui.router'
        ]);
})();
```

I defined controllers and modules and everything in my html.

Everything is working smooth on mozila and chrome but not on Safari :( 
Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Is the `TranslateController` file explicitly loaded before the config block with routes? (btw, your `$urlRouterProvider` is not being used)

Comment: Yes and my load is structure this way. 
<!-- library -->
  <!-- Main app load -->
  <!-- Modules -->
  <!-- Config routes -->
  <!-- controllers -->
  <!-- Services -->


  <!-- Directive -->

Comment: Solved my problem by rewriting controllers to regular angular style controller  like

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('welcome.module')
  .controller('TranslateController', ['$scope', '$translate',
    function($scope, $translate) {
      $scope.headerFix = true;

      activate();

      function activate() {
        translate();
      }

      function translate() {
        $scope.changeLanguage = function(langKey) {
          $translate.use(langKey);
        };
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Fixed it